# VBA - saving every sheet as values in excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to loop through every worksheet in the active workbook, and save all formulas as values. To do this, for each sheet, first I run through each pivot table, then select the table and copy & paste as values. Then I am trying to use the `worksheet.activerange.value = .value` method to save the rest of the cells in the sheet.

I am getting  a 1004 runtime error on the line `wks.UsedRange.Value = wks.UsedRange.Value`.

I have two questions:

1) How can I fix my runtime error?

2) Is there a way to get .value = .value to work with pivot tables? In previous macros this has never worked with pivots, so I have to use copy and paste as below.

Many thanks for your help!

```
Sub LockWorkbook()

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = 1

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    i = 1
    For Each pvt In wks.PivotTables
        wks.PivotTables(i).TableRange2.Select
        With Selection
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlValues
            .PasteSpecial xlFormats
        End With
        i = i + 1
        Next pvt

    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(n)
    wks.UsedRange.Value = wks.UsedRange.Value
    n = n + 1

    Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be usedrange.formula = usedrange.value.  im sorry I might be wrong.

Comment: Also, pivot tables can*not* contain formulas.  They can only contain values, so you should not need a macro like this.

Comment: Wouldnt cells.copy    cells.pastespecial xlValues    work for whole sheet including pivot

Answer (score 1):

On The King's point, you can simply copy and paste the whole sheet as values.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").cells.copy
Sheets("Sheet1").cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

If you wanted to throw that in a simple loop to do it to all pages it can look like:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer


    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Next I

End Sub
```

Please let me know if that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Latest edit eliminates Run-time error '1004' (excludes Pivot Tables from conversion to values)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertFormulasToValuesInUsedRangeExceptPivotTables()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, cel As Range
    Dim pvt As PivotTable, nonPivot As Range, isPvt As Boolean

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange

        For Each cel In ur

            For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables      'excludes pivot tables
                isPvt = Not Intersect(cel, pvt.TableRange2) Is Nothing
                If isPvt Then Exit For
            Next

            If Not isPvt Then
                If Len(cel.Formula) > 0 Then    'excludes empty cells
                    If nonPivot Is Nothing Then
                        Set nonPivot = cel
                    Else
                        Set nonPivot = Union(nonPivot, cel)
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Next cel

        nonPivot.Value = nonPivot.Value
        Set nonPivot = Nothing

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error" on the line "ws.usedrange.value = ws.usedrange.value". Any ideas?

Comment: OK so it works with a simple workbook (i open a new file and through a few sum()'s around). But it won't work with a more complicated file (containing pivots, conditional formatting, merged cells and links to other files). Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Your last comment is good - I only tested it with a simple file (with 3 pivot tables). I think the pivots are not causing the problem but I'll add more formulas, validation rules, conditional formatting, merged cells, and links to other files. Anything else you had in the file? Also - what was the error number and description?

Comment: Always  "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error".

Comment: Latest edit (very late) eliminates Run-time error '1004' (excludes Pivot Tables from conversion to values)